# how to correct below expression in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want to set the dynamic width in ngStyle. how can i write the expression correct.

```
[ngStyle]="{{'width': 'calc(chargeStation.response[1].width+'%' - 1+'px')' }}"
```

i have changed to

```
[ngStyle]="{'width': 'calc('+ chargeStation.response[1].width +'%'+ ')'}"
```

than in HTML its taking as object

```
ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"
```

Comment: the Niraji answer is correct. See if your chargeStation.response[1].width has value -remember that an array begins by 0 index-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below solution, it's working for me.

in template file (.html)

```
<button [ngStyle]="{'width': 'calc(' + chargeStation.width + '% - 1px)'}" (click)="buttonClick()">click</button>
```

in component file (.ts)

you have to assign value to your object in ts file
For Example I have chargeStation object with width property.
property has 100 value.

```
chargeStation = {
    width: 100
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

directives accepts objects; so you don't have to add {{}}

```
[ngStyle]="{width: chargeStation.response[1].width - 1 + 'px'}"
```

Comment: I have used this but its not parsing correctly. its have the 
** ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" **

Comment: that is something with calc. Also why you need calc when you can compute from js

Comment: I awnt to calc the witdth using %. like [ngStyle]="{'width': 'calc('+ chargeStation.response[1].width + '%' + ')'}"

Comment: width is just not the width its % value , we need to calc the width in % -1px